# Can not Deserialize json object to model class type

Tags: c#, json

I have the below `JSON` Data and `Model` class.I try to Deserialize the `JSON` object to a `Model` Class data , but it shows an ERROR message:

> Cannot deserialize JSON object into type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[eInvoice.Model.errors]'.

I have tried the below code but it does not work.
Please check this code and advise me how to Deserialize a `JSON` object to a `Model` class data.

**Json Object :**

```
 [
  {
    "custom_fields": null,
    "document_status": "NOT_CREATED",
    "error_response": null,
    "errors": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "error_code": "101",
          "error_message": "Invoice with the Same Transaction ID is Present In the Database",
          "error_source": "CLEARTAX"
        }
      ]
    },
    "govt_response": {
      "Success": "N",
      "ErrorDetails": [
        {
          "error_code": "2150",
          "error_message": "Duplicate IRN",
          "error_source": "GOVT"
        }
      ],
      "info": [
        {
          "InfCd": "DUPIRN",
          "Desc": {
            "AckNo": 112010005972781,
            "AckDt": "2020-09-19 10:17:00",
            "Irn": "7ed6484c750e09c2bbaea84ce69909b434e0a9e8767f0e535e04eb268f3a5a1b"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "group_id": null,
    "gstin": "29AAFCD5862R000",
    "owner_id": "78c6beda-54a2-11ea-b064-0af3f8b02c24",
    "transaction": {
     },
    "transaction_id": "29AAFCD5862R000_G/E/20-21/0187_INV_2020",
    "transaction_metadata": null
  }
]
```

**Model Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace eInvoice.Model
{
    public class responses
    {        
        public response response { get; set; }

    }
    public class response
    {
        public string custom_fields { get; set; }
        public string document_status { get; set; }
        public string error_response { get; set; }
        public List<errors> errors { get; set; }
        public govt_response govt_response { get; set; }
        public string group_id { get; set; }
        public string gstin { get; set; }
        public string owner_id { get; set; }

        public transaction transaction { get; set; }

    }

    public class errors
    {
        public string error_code { get; set; }
        public string error_message { get; set; }
        public string error_source { get; set; }
        
    }
    public class govt_response
    {
        public string Success { get; set; }
        public string AckNo { get; set; }
        public string AckDt { get; set; }
        public string Irn { get; set; }
        public string SignedInvoice { get; set; }
        public string SignedQRCode { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<ErrorDetails> ErrorDetails { get; set; }
        public List<info> info { get; set; }
    }
    public class ErrorDetails
    {
        public string error_code { get; set; }
        public string error_message { get; set; }
        public string error_source { get; set; }

    }

    public class info
    {
        public string InfCd { get; set; }
    }
    public class Desc
    {
        public string AckNo { get; set; }
        public string AckDt { get; set; }
        public string Irn { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**Source Code for Deserialize :**

```
List<response> res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<response>>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: How does `jsonstring` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your json file you first have the json object called `errors`, which has the array `errors`. But your `response` class contains the property of type `List<errors>`, so I think it should have a property of a type which would define a property of type `List<errors>`.

Change your `errors` class to something like this and add a new class to represent a single error. I think it should work.

```
public class jsonErrors
{
   public List<error> errors { get; set; }
}

public class error
{
   public string error_code { get; set; }
   public string error_message { get; set; }
   public string error_source { get; set; }
}
```

And by the way you should change also `errors` property in the response class to:

```
public class response
{
    ...
    public jsonErrors errors { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'd like also to call your attention to how you name your classes and properties. Usually classes and properties in C# are named using **CamelCase** style having first letter capitalized.